# Stitch columns horizontally in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `slide_style_info` (
  `ssi_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slide_style_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `input_type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `input_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_value` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ssi_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and values:

```
1   |1  |Text               |Text 1         |First text here
2   |1  |Text               |Text 2         |Second text here
3   |2  |Text               |Text 1         |First text here
4   |1  |Text               |Text 3         |Third text here
5   |1  |Font Family        |Font Family 1  |Comic Sans
6   |1  |Font Family        |Font Family 2  |Comic Sans
7   |1  |Font Family        |Font Family 3  |Comic Sans
8   |2  |Font Family        |Font Family 1  |Comic Sans
```

I would like to select all  rows where `slide_style_id = 1`, but display the result is such format:

```
1   |1  |Text               |Text 1         |First text here      |Font Family      |Font Family 1  |Comic Sans
2   |1  |Text               |Text 2         |Second text here     |Font Family      |Font Family 2  |Comic Sans
4   |1  |Text               |Text 3         |Third text here      |Font Family      |Font Family 1  |Comic Sans
```

can this be done with sql?

The solution I was hoping for would use:

```
SELECT `input_type`, `input_name`
FROM `scene_style_info`
WHERE `scene_style_id` = 1
AND `input_type` = "Text"
ORDER BY `input_name`
```

and

```
SELECT `input_type`, `input_name`
FROM `scene_style_info`
WHERE `scene_style_id` = 1
AND `input_type` = "Font Family"
ORDER BY `input_name`
```

Now I have the values I need in the correct order, but I am not aware of any way to stitch these columns horizontally.

Comment: how do you link Text with Font Family? For ex: how do you know Text 1 goes with Font Family 1?

Comment: Order by input_name would suffice i think. Text 1 always matches with Font Family 1

Comment: I could also add an additional identifier to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you waiting for us? yes, make it clear

Answer (score 0):

this isn't really a solution, just observation

I think your request is only partially possible from the facts you have provided.

It LOOKS LIKE you could relate this row

```
ssi_id | slide_style_id | input_type | input_name | default_value 
3      |2                |Text       |Text 1      |First text here
```

to this row because they share **a common slide_style_id value of 2**

```
ssi_id | slide_style_id | input_type | input_name    | default_value 
8      |2               |Font Family  Font Family 1  |Comic Sans
```

and the result would be a single row, similar to those included in the question

but using that same logic, EACH of these three rows:

```
ssi_id | slide_style_id | input_type | input_name | default_value 
1      |1               |Text        |Text 1      |First text here
2      |1               |Text        |Text 2      |Second text here
4      |1               |Text        |Text 3      |Third text here
```

would relate to EACH of these 3 rows

```
ssi_id | slide_style_id | input_type | input_name    | default_value 
5      |1               |Font Family |Font Family 1  |Comic Sans
6      |1               |Font Family |Font Family 2  |Comic Sans
7      |1               |Font Family |Font Family 3  |Comic Sans
```

and the result would be 3x3 = 9 rows

My point being that you haven't supplied us with any logical way to produce the desired result using SQL.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I've added the option I was hoping for and also found the right words to describe it.